# SST 39VF1602 - NOR or NAND?

Tags: flash, nand-flash

I have this flash chip, and I cannot figure out if it is a NOR or a NAND flash chip.

Here is the 
[datasheet](https://www.rockbox.org/wiki/pub/Main/DataSheets/S71223.pdf).

From the capacity of the chip (2M), I am assuming that it is a NOR chip, but I am not sure. How can you tell the type of this chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's implemented as a single array of parallel addressed and accessed memory, with conventional address bus A[n:0], data bus D[15:0] and control bus (/OE, /WE, /CE).

It is a NOR flash.